# Remember session after user closes the browser in joomla

Tags: session, cookies, joomla

I don't know much about joomla. I found this:

JFactory::getSession();

Here I found that there is an expire date, but I can't make it work.
http://www.techportal.co.za/joomla/joomla-tutorials/304

Could you give an working example?

Just want when a user reopen the browser the data stored in the last session to be available. Also have to say that I'm using an outside domain to login, so in this case I don't care about internal ways of joomla handling users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4 sections you can see in the documentation you're using there need to be passed through in an array (called `$options` in the API)

So you'd need to pass

```
$time=99; //time in minutes
$options = array(
    "expire" => $time,
);
$session =& JFactory::getSession($options);
```

Note by default this is handled by a param in the config area of Joomla in 2.5 upwards! This might well also be the case in 1.5 - I don't have a copy of 1.5 to hand.